# Getting connection is closed for long running Connections

Tags: spring-boot, envoyproxy

I have an spring boot application which is connecting to postgresql with hickaricp connection pool.

I have installed envoy proxy to encrypt the communication, In this case I am getting below errors for long running connections.

java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please put more details on what configuration you are using for your connection pool?

There are parameters like connectionTimeout,idleTimeout,maxLifetime for tuning the hikari pool. For eg:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000 
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000 
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
```

Here is a list of all the settings which can be provided while configuring the connection pools.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#frequently-used

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring.datasource.hikari

Using these can help here.

Comment: I am using below parameters in my application.
connectionTimeout=4000
idleTimeout=60000
maximumPoolSize=128
maxLifetime=1800000

Comment: I am facing this issue only when envoy proxy is enabled between application and database.

Comment: Facing same. How you fixed this issue?